# Add joint primary key to wordpress posts table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am working out how to synchronize wordpress installations where both can be updated simultaneously, and both can work offline, then come online to sync.

I think the easiest way to sync posts between sites, is to include the site id in the primary key of the posts. Therefore, any post is identified by an incremental id and the id of the server location it was created from.

Is this possible to achieve with a plugin?
What dangers lie ahead if I pursue this path?
Is there a better, alternative way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in several ways:
- Write a stored procedure inside the first Wordpress installation's php files, that inserts the content into the other database when something is written to it. This one probably won't work offline.
- Write a function that compares the two databases at a schedule time using a simple sql query and creates a diff log. Then copies over the difference to the other database.

It depends why you need to do this, but if this works, I would recommend this solution:
- Keep one wordpress installation. Maintain one database, and connect to it from the other website to load the content. You can create your own SQL connection to it and load whatever content you need.
- Keep one wordpress installation, and use it's RSS feed to read the content and display it in whichever second website you need to do it in.

I can't imagine how a plugin would be of much help, especially keeping the databases in sync offline too. In my experience, its usually better to write your custom php scripts, rather than use a plugin so you can have a more direct control over the functionality.

Hope this helps.